# How to get td innerhtml values except input type="hidden" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i created a dynamic table. it can be dynamically add,edit and remove rows.
When adding every `td` inside the table it also add a hidden field that contain value. that is,

```
<tr>
<td>This is Text <input type="hidden" value="someValue"></td>
</tr>
```

here is the code to get the innerHtml inside the td element.

```
var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");

tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
```

But when i using this code it show the text with input hidden type. That is,

```
This is Text <input type="hidden" value="someValue">
```

Here i dont want to get the hidden input field. I only need other part that is `This is Text` . Is it possible?

i tried `tdName.children("input[type!=hidden]").val()`
But it doesnt works.

Comment: So you dont want to get the value of textbox that is hidden type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var txt = tdname.contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Filter it by text node
}).text();
```

```js
var txt = $('.test').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Filter it by text node
}).text();

alert(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="test">This is Text
            <input type="hidden" value="someValue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.text()` to get the text in that row:

```
tdname.children().text()
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLqLsge7/)

Comment: @rohi post your full code or better yet recreate the issue in a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hidden` selector, It will return only visible elements:

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u66ez4gv/

You need that:

```
tdName.children("input:visible").val()
```